# How to get previous row data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find out what is the previous ID, how can that be done?

Find ID 5:

```
SELECT id FROM status` WHERE id = 5 ORDER BY order_status ASC
```

Now I want get previous ID depending on `ORDER order_status ASC`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the MAX() function in combination with a WHERE like this:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM status WHERE id < 5
```

Note the `ORDER BY` has no use as you are only selecting one row